¿Cómo implementar una firma electrónica en un documento PDF con OpenSSL en PHP?
Estoy desarrollando una plataforma en PHP en la que algunos usuarios suben documentos PDF y otros, con rol de aprobadores, los revisan y firman digitalmente si la información es correcta. Actualmente, esta firma digital es solo una imagen escaneada insertada en el PDF, sin ningún tipo de cifrado o validación de autenticidad. Me gustaría mejorar esta funcionalidad implementando una firma electrónica real usando OpenSSL para garantizar la integridad y autenticidad del documento firmado.
He investigado sobre el uso de OpenSSL en PHP para generar claves y certificados, pero no tengo claro cómo aplicarlo específicamente en la firma de un PDF. Agradecería mucho cualquier orientación o ejemplo sobre cómo puedo firmar digitalmente un PDF con OpenSSL en PHP, o si existe algún método estándar para ello.
P.D. la plataforma la tengo alojada en servidor compartido

Este no es el tipo de preguntas que se esperan aquí, donde se responde sobre problemas concretos, no sobre formas de hacer las cosas.

Te refieres a que esta pregunta no es adecuada para stackoverflow en general o que debo poner la pregunta en alguna categoría especifica?

En general, no es adecuada, porque no es sobre un problema concreto. Se espera que intentes alguna forma de hacer lo que quieres, y si te encuentras alguna traba que no consigues resolver por ti mismo, puedes exponerla aquí. Sé que a veces gustaría tener una respuesta rápida para orientarte sobre cómo hacer algo, pero aquí es para problemas concretos, ya metidos en código. Mejor haz una simple búsqueda en Google, yo encontré esto, quizá te sirva: https://guiaphp.com/seguridad/firmar-de-documentos-en-php-pdf-con-certificado-personal/

Entiendo, muchas gracias por tu tiempo y la aclaración, además por la orientación, eliminaré la pregunta
